# Provide feedback message in textarea based on mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I am pulling the data out of two columns in a mysql database and visually representing it in a line graph. Below were the graph is displayed on the webpage i want to put in a textarea that offers a feedback message based on the data shown in the graph. I was wondering would this be possible by using if else statements? I am trying to figure out how i would put the set the text if a condition is met into the textarea itself. would it be something like this for example? Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
    $MilkSolids = $row['milk_solids'];
    $TagNumber= $row['tag_number'];
    $average = '50';

  $myquery = "SELECT  `milk_solids`, `tag_number` FROM  `milk` ";
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery);



if($Milksolids > 50)
{
<textarea rows="2" cols="20">
<?php 
echo "good feedback message"; ?>
</textarea>
}
else($Milksolids < $average)
{
<textarea rows="2" cols="20">
<?php 
echo "bad feedback message"; ?>
</textarea>

}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you putting the 'feedback message' in a textarea? Do you intend the user to be able to edit this after the feedback is put in the area by php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest building the markup in a PHP variable, and then echoing the markup all at once:

```
<?php
    $average = '50';

    $myquery = "SELECT  `milk_solids`, `tag_number` FROM  `milk` ";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery);

    $MilkSolids = $row['milk_solids'];
    $TagNumber= $row['tag_number'];

    if ($row['milk_solids'] > 50) {
        $msg = 'good feedback message';
    }elseif ($Milksolids < $average) {
        $msg = 'bad feedback message';
    }else{
        $msg = 'some other message';
    }

    $out = '<textarea rows="2" cols="20">' .$msg. '</textarea>';
    echo $out;
?>
```

Note that you must place these lines after both (1) the `mysql_query` and (2) the `mysql_fetch_assoc` statements:

```
    $MilkSolids = $row['milk_solids'];
    $TagNumber= $row['tag_number'];
```

Comment: gh0st has a good point above -- consider placing the message in DIV tags. Markup would look like this: `$out = '<div id="feedback_msg>' .$msg. '</div>';`

Comment: Thanks for the help, Would it be possible to specify the specific tag numbers in the text area. For instance, "the production levels of cow with tag number 432321<tag_number> are not meeting the expected levels". Would a for each loop be used in this case to iterate through all the tag numbers in the table, i am just not too sure how to go about it.

Comment: If you want this question answered quickly, accept an answer for this question (since you are now asking a slightly different -- though related --  question) and ask a new question. You will get dozens of new helpers instead of only one. :)